# Span TikZ Picture Across Two Columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, two-column

I'm restricted to writing a paper with`\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}`, but I want to create a `tikzpicture` that spans across both of the columns, filling the width of the page. I have tried placing it in a `figure` and using `figure*`, and other figure options, but none of that works.

The code for my `tikzpicture` is here.

```
\definecolor {processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\begin {center}
\begin {tikzpicture}[-latex ,auto ,node distance =1.8cm and 1.5cm ,on grid ,
semithick ,
state/.style ={ circle ,top color =white , bottom color = processblue!20 ,
draw,processblue , text=blue , minimum width =1 cm}]
\node[state] (S) {$S$};
\node[state] (W) [above right =of S] {$W$};
\node[state] (X) [right =of W] {$X$};
\node[state] (Y) [right =of X] {$Y$};
\node[state] (Z) [right =of Y] {$Z$};
\node[state] (D) [below right =of Z] {$D$};
\path (S) edge [bend left =0] node[above left = .3 cm] {$R_{sw}$} (W);
\path (W) edge  [bend right =0](S);
\path (W) edge [bend left =0] node[above = .3 cm] {$R_{wx}$}(X);
\path (X) edge [bend right =0](W);
\path (X) edge [bend left =0] node[above = .3 cm] {$R_{xy}$}(Y);
\path (Y) edge [bend right =0](X);
\path (Y) edge [bend left =0] node[above = .3 cm] {$R_{yz}$}(Z);
\path (Z) edge [bend right =0](Y);
\path (Z) edge [bend left =0] node[above right = .3 cm] {$R_{zd}$}(D);
\path (D) edge [bend right =0](Z);
{\tiny }\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: What's precisely the problem with `figure*`?

Comment: @egreg a `tikzpicture` in a `figure*` takes on the column width, not the figure width.

Comment: @JAB A `tikzpicture` takes its own width.

Comment: @egreg You seem to be correct, I thought I had observed the dimensions changing based on column size but after some more experimentation it seems not.

Comment: @JAB In Jesse's solution, the picture is magnified by `adjustbox`

Comment: @egreg Yeah, I noticed that when I tried it. In fact, I should clarify something: I'm sizing a pgf plot rather than a normal tikz figure. It seems that just setting `width=\textwidth` on the axis is the simplest solution.

Comment: @JAB I don't think `figure*` resets `\linewidth`; `\textwidth` is certainly better in such an environment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a way to span the `tikzpicture` across two column. `adjustbox` package is used where the width is set to `\linewidth` for the span. width=`\columnwidth` would back to regular result.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum,adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\definecolor {processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\begin {figure*}%[!hbtp]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin {tikzpicture}[-latex ,auto,node distance =1.8cm and 1.5cm ,on grid,semithick,
state/.style ={ circle ,top color =white , bottom color = processblue!20,
draw,processblue , text=blue , minimum width =1 cm}]
\node[state] (S) {$S$};
\node[state] (W) [above right =of S] {$W$};
\node[state] (X) [right =of W] {$X$};
\node[state] (Y) [right =of X] {$Y$};
\node[state] (Z) [right =of Y] {$Z$};
\node[state] (D) [below right =of Z] {$D$};
\path (S) edge [bend left =0] node[above left = .3 cm] {$R_{sw}$} (W);
\path (W) edge  [bend right =0](S);
\path (W) edge [bend left =0] node[above = .3 cm] {$R_{wx}$}(X);
\path (X) edge [bend right =0](W);
\path (X) edge [bend left =0] node[above = .3 cm] {$R_{xy}$}(Y);
\path (Y) edge [bend right =0](X);
\path (Y) edge [bend left =0] node[above = .3 cm] {$R_{yz}$}(Z);
\path (Z) edge [bend right =0](Y);
\path (Z) edge [bend left =0] node[above right = .3 cm] {$R_{zd}$}(D);
\path (D) edge [bend right =0](Z);
{\tiny }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```